# Prove the dominated convergence for $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that we have $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^2+3x+2}$.

- $f_n$ don't have uniform convergence because the pointwise isn't continuous:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(1)$$
- To prove that $\{f_n\}$ has dominated convergence we need an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

> But if the pointwise isn't continuous for every $x\in[0,1]$, how we can show the dominated convergence? Or for dominated convergence isn't necessary to have a continuous pointwise limit for every $x\in[0,1]$ ?

- By the way, how can I prove that $f_n\leq g$ where $g$ is integrable ? I suppose $g$ can be $1$ which is integrable on the interval but how can I prove inequality such that $f_n\leq 1$ ? or something else, not necessarily $1$...

Comment: If $x\in[0,1]$, $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{(x+1)(x+2)}\leq \frac{1}{1\cdot 2}.$$

Comment: Moreover, since $f_{n+1}(x)\leq f_{n}(x)$, the most natural candidate for a dominating function is just $f_1(x)$.

Comment: hi Jack, can you give me some explanations for yellow box ? as I said the pointwise convergence isn't continous, but in dominated convergence isn't neccessary this condition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{n}}{x^{2}+3x+2}\leq \frac{1}{0+0+2}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and the constant function $\frac{1}{2}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

To answer the part in the yellow box: the dominated convergence theorem does not require that the point-wise limit is a continuous function.

Comment: Thomas can you ask at the yellow box?

Comment: @Lucas: I edited the answer and included that part too. For further reference for dominated convergence theorem, the wikipedia article has a lot of information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: Thomas, so we can say that $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $0$, $\forall x\in[0,1]$ or $x\in[0,1)$ ? I mean in dominated convergence not uniform

Comment: @lucas: The point wise convergence to zero happens for all $x\in [0,1)$. At $x=1$ the limit is not zero, but the single point $x=1$ has measure zero and thus does not contribute to the value of the integral.

Comment: Thomas for $x=1\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ will be $\frac{1}{6}$ I don't understand what you want to say by "$x=1$ has measure zero.."

Comment: @lucas: Yes that's true. You can ignore the comment about measure zero: I thought you we're dealing with integration through measure theory, but you can also view the integral as a Riemann integral. That's fine too.

Comment: but Thomas when you say "thus does not contribute to the value of the integral" is what I want to sound, because $\int_0^1 f_n(x)=\int_0^1 f(pointwise)dx$ and this is what I don't understand if our integral is defined on $[0,1]$ which is the pointwise convergent: $0$ or $\frac {1}{6}$ ?

Comment: @Lucas: The conclusion is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)$. And $f(x)=0$ if $x\in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=\frac{1}{6}$. This limit function is defined on the whole interval $[0,1]$ and is discontinuous. The reason why $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)=0$ requires measure theory: the set $\{1\}$ has measure zero and thus its contribution to the integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)$ is negligible. To fully understand this, a good place to start is to google "Lebesgue measure" and "Lebesgue integral".